# finding max value from multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an array of dim 4x1x4x71x128.
The first dim refers to 4 different models. 
The third dim refers to lower CI, Correlation, Upper CI and p-value.

What I need as output is a new array of dim 1x1x1x71x128 where the first dim refers to the max value of Correlation(3rd dim) among the 4 models(1st dim).

I tried the following:

```
newarray <- array(NA, c(1,1,1,71,128))
for (i in 1:4) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(array[1,1,1,,])) {
    for (k in 1:ncol(array[1,1,1,,])){
      newarray[i,1,1,j,k] <- max(array[i,1,1,j,k], na.rm = FALSE)
    }
  }
}
```

This returns me the maximum value not for Correlation but for lower CI. However, when I change operation to:

```
newarray[i,1,1,j,k] <- max(array[i,1,2,j,k], na.rm = FALSE)
```

It does not work. I believe I am not looping right but can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: Did you try `apply(array,c(2,4,5),max)`?

Comment: It will help to have reproducible example with expected results - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @nicola Unfortunately, the suggested code gives me NA values

Comment: @ Bulat I tried to reproduce an example with expected results: 

     `testarray <- array(sample(1:16), c(2,1,2,2,2))`
     `resultarray <- array(c(12,14,13,7), c(1,1,1,2,2))`
     `testarray[,1,2,,] # to compare results`
     `resultarray[1,1,1,,] # max value for each grid point`

Answer (score 1):

```
x.max <- apply(x , c(3,4,5) , 
                   function(x) 
                     ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Solved!
Result is of dim 4x71x128 with the 2nd element of 1st dim being the desired output.